# Why is data hiding a key part of OOP and not Imperative or Functional programming?

Tags: python, oop, data-hiding

Is it used in other programming paradigms as well? What would be a good example of when and when not to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, this is a very broad topic and it differs very much from the language/environment in wich you are working.

For example python doesn't really spend much thought about encapsulation: [Why are Python's 'private' methods not actually private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70528/why-are-pythons-private-methods-not-actually-private)

The "best" example for encapsulation would be pimpl from c++:
[How do you do "true" encapsulation in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847719/how-do-you-do-true-encapsulation-in-c)

Encapsulation only makes real sense, when you want someone to not mess around with your inner variables.

If you got full source accesss to such things, you can always have a look, change things ( for the better or the worse ).

So, lets say, you are a software developer for the navigational system of a car. The manufacturer gave you an api-doc how to connect to the car, you can access informations via functions ( eg, get gps coordinates ) and can set informations yourself via functions.
But the software handling the engine, is most likely hidden/locked for your navigation software ( well, in most cases its done badly... but just for example reasons)
A good example would be the horse-power variable ( dunno if it exists ), you shoulnt be able to see/set/get that number in your navigation software... and thats all the fuss is about.